# what is the probability that $x < y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If a real number x is chosen at random in the interval $[0, 3]$, and a real number $y$ is chosen at random in the interval $[0, 4]$, what is the probability that $x < y$ ?

---

Is this an application of Normal Distribution ?

Comment: Use independence to obtain the joint pdf of $x$ and $y$ then integrate it over the region $x<y$.

Answer (score 3):

Break up the range of $y $ into two parts: $y>3$ and $0\geq y \geq 3$. We then consider the probability of $y>x $ in each case and add them up.

In case $1$, $y $ is always $> x$, so the probability that we choose $y $ in this interval is $\frac {1}{4} $.

In case $2$, as both $x $ and $y $ are in the same range, we can **logically conclude** that $y>x$ half the time. As the probability of choosing a $y $ in this range is $\frac {3}{4} $, the total probability is $\frac {1}{2}\times \frac {3}{4} = \frac {3}{8} $. Hence, $$\boxed {P_{\text {tot}} = P_1 +P_2 = \frac {1}{4} + \frac {3}{8} = \frac{5}{8}}$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

No; presumably these are uniformly random variables.

Use the Law of Total Probability:

$$P(x<y) = P(x<y\mid y<3)~P(y<3)+P(x<y\mid y\geq 3)~P(y\geq 3)$$

You should be able to work out these conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X\sim\text{Uniform}(0,3)$ and $Y\sim\text{Uniform}(0,4)$:

$$P(X<Y)=\int_0^3\int_x^4 f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$$

Then using independence:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Thus:

$$P(X<Y)=\int_0^3\int_x^4 \frac{1}{12}dydx=\int_0^3\frac{4-x}{12}dx=\frac{5}{8}$$